# A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the MSDTC service

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

Experiencing this intermittent issue on a few servers running MSDTC.

```
19/09/2018 10:54:38 a.m. -- A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the MSDTC$cde1a4e7-dc9d-4ae3-89b9-8114147ae420 service.

19/09/2018 10:54:38 a.m. -- Cluster resource 'MSDTC-SQLServer' of type 'Distributed Transaction Coordinator' in clustered role 'SQL Server' failed.

19/09/2018 10:54:57 a.m. -- The Distributed Transaction Coordinator (cde1a4e7-dc9d-4ae3-89b9-8114147ae420) service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 12 time(s).
```

All these servers run trend micro deep security agent ( Anti Malware protection and Intrusion Prevention ). The issue completely goes away when AV is turned off. But having the AV turned off for long is not an option.

Have configured the following AV exclusions for MSDTC.

1. MSDTC Service
2. MSDTC Log file
3. MSDTC Log Folder

are there any more exclusions that I should get added ?

Comment: Look into the cluster log to see why the cluster marked it as failed and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding the MSDTC log file with the full path in AV ( Trend Micro ) fixed the issue.